# Import Csv file with 8 million Records

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel, excel-2013

I have a `CSV` file containing around 8 Million Records, I am trying to import it in Microsoft Excel 2013. Looks like its taking up only 1 Million and omitting the rest.

Can any one tell me how to import all the records properly without any data loss?

Comment: One Excel sheet can contain 2^20 = 1,048,576 rows maximum. So you would need 8 sheets for your data. The import wizard will not separate the data in different sheets. For this task programming is needed. But if you would have the data on 8 sheets, what then? Why having so much data in Excel? This is not useful in my opinion.

Comment: What are you doing with the data once it's in excel? processing it? summarising it? No one can visually inspect 8 million records and it would be difficult to get Excel to process it in any way.

Comment: Millions of lines should better stay in database than in an Excel file. One 1M lines excel can take minutes to open on an average computer and requires a lot of RAM (virtual memory). What do you want to do with this data?

Comment: Look into Power Query. You import and load into a data model, and run pivot tables from that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *[Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ&fromAR=1)*, worksheets are limited to 1 048 576 rows. You can have as many worksheets as your computer can handle before it exhausts memory.

This file must be loaded into few worksheets. The best approach would be splitting it into eight slices (there are few tools available if you search the web for "split text file Windows" - I have never used any of them) and then load them sequentially into Excel. VBA can you help in second part.

But I'm not sure if that format (one file split into eight sheets) would be suitable for any useful analysis.

I would say that **Excel is not right tool for this job**.